# Why typescript doesn't show error when i implicit cast {...T , [key of T ]: T[keyof T] } as T in a function

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

In TS playground and my vscode, the following code does not show any problems.

Is {[x: keyof T]: T[keyof T]} a subset of T?

```
function mergeCell(
    row: T,
    cellKey: keyof T,
    newValue: T[keyof T]
): T {
    return { ...row, [cellKey]: newValue };
}

interface MyObj {
    a: string;
    b: boolean;
    c: number;
}

const obj = { a: '1', b: false, c: 2 };
const result : MyObj = mergeCell(obj, 'c', 'c');
console.log(result);

Result is as follow without error
: {
    "a": "1",
    "b": false,
    "c": "c"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is expected. When you do `newValue: T[keyof T]`, `T[keyof T]` can be translated as `T[give me any any key of T]` whereas what you'd like here should rather be `T[the key I've specified in other property]`.

To be more concrete, `keyof T` in this case gives us `a`, `b`, `c` and `T[keyof T]` is therefore equivalent to `T[a | b | c]` which is equivalent to  `string | boolean | number`. Because you passed a string, it's still valid and Typescript is happy.

So

```js
function mergeCell<T, U extends keyof T>(
  row: T,
  cellKey: U,
  newValue: T[U]
): T {
  return { ...row, [cellKey]: newValue };
}
```

Should be

```js
function mergeCell<T, U extends keyof T>(
  row: T,
  cellKey: U,
  newValue: T[U]
): T {
  return { ...row, [cellKey]: newValue };
}
```

Here, you pass a key `U` and for the new value, you explicitly specify that you want **the type of the associated value for that key**.

As you can see in [this live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-qrmqmn?file=index.ts), you get an error as expected now.